# Current location using geolocator

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get current location using geolocator sdk of flutter.But I am getting this error.

This is the stack trace

```
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-2.1.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/flutter/plugin/geolocator/tasks/LastKnownLocationUsingLocationServicesTask.java:4: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-2.1.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/flutter/plugin/geolocator/tasks/LocationUpdatesUsingLocationServicesTask.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am trying to get current location here like this

```
    class _MapActivityState extends State<MapActivity> {

      Position currentLocation;

      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
       getUserLocation();
      }
        @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MapboxMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 15),
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
      ),
    );
  }
      Future<Position> locateUser() async {
        return Geolocator()
            .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      }

      getUserLocation() async {
        currentLocation = await locateUser();
        print(currentLocation);
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is very old post but you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487599/error-in-compilation-with-geolocator-pluggin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `LastKnownLocationUsingLocationServicesTask` file, delete the import statement which is causing this error, again import it using `option + enter`, I have seen this issue while using `geolocator`.

Similarly, open `LocationUpdatesUsingLocationServicesTask` file and delete import (with errors) and reimport it.

Comment: where is this file?

Comment: If you are using Android studio, you can use shortcut `cmd + shift + o` and type the file name.

Comment: You need top open this file in Android studio module, you are currently opening it in flutter module. See [how to open it in android module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548771/6618622).

Comment: When you open `build.gradle` file it ask you to open this for editing in Android studio, when you do that, it will open up in a new window where you can open `LastKnownLocationUsingLocationServicesTask` using shortcut and delete imports.

Comment: I'm sorry I never got a chance to use maps, so I can't help you with that. Seems like I know you because I have answered your question yesterday? Glad to see you accepting answers.

Comment: yup. That's the reason I am asking you .You helped me out yesterday also