# Signing a Flutter App with Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, release, playback

I have problems in uploading a standard app on google play. I get following error:

You uploaded an APK or Android app bundle that was signed in debug mode. Upload an APK or Android app bundle that was signed in release mode. Learn more about signing.

I am not sure what I was doing wrong. I went to Build -> Flutter -> Build App Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Signing the app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app). It clearly says:

> To publish on the Play Store, you need to give your app a digital
> signature. Use the following instructions to sign your app.
>
> On Android, there are two signing keys: deployment and upload. The
> end-users download the .apk signed with the ‘deployment key’. An
> ‘upload key’ is used to authenticate the .aab / .apk uploaded by
> developers onto the Play Store and is re-signed with the deployment
> key once in the Play Store.

Comment: Yes, I read this. I am unsure if I did all the steps necessary to get the upload key in my program appropriately.

I also have a situation like this: 

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539171/flutter-in-android-studio-build-bundle-apk-greyed-out

Comment: So what output do you get from flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle?